# I'm getting a SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, html, json, parsing

I'm pretty new to Javascript and in a kind of trouble. I'm tryien to parse a Json file in my js code. I'm getting the error mentioned in the title all the time. It seems like my json is wrong formated but I already checked this. I don't know what's the problem.
The error occurs at JSON.parse()

```
    document.getElementById('loadjson').addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var jsonData = document.getElementById('jsondata').value;
      
      fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5500/src/main/resources/savedData.json')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => console.log(data))
        .then(function(data) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(data);
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 
            obj.pages[0].url;
        });
      
    });
```

```
    {
       "pages":[
          {
             "wikipage":{
                "latestModifier":{
                   
                },
                "author":{
                   "name":"some name",
                   "username":"some userid"
                },
                "latest_modification":"Tue Mar 14 10:42:33 CET 2017",
                "url":"some url"
             }
          },
          {
             "wikipage":{
                "latestModifier":{
                   
                },
                "author":{
                   "name":"some name",
                   "username":"some userid"
                },
                "latest_modification":"Thu Jun 08 08:12:38 CEST 2017",
                "url":"some url"
             }
          }
       ]
    }
```

Comment: All data is fetched correctly and printed in the console

Comment: What do you thing `console.log()` returns?

Comment: I don't know. I thought it just prints the given parameter into the console

Comment: To spell it out, `console.log()` returns `undefined` so your second `.then()` resolves with that value, passing it on to the next `.then()` (hence the "u" at position 0). Also, you're already parsing the JSON response via `response.json()` so there's no need to try and parse it again with `JSON.parse()`. Voting to close as a typo

Comment: Try `.then(response => response.json()).then(obj => { ... })` and go from there, no `JSON.parse()` required

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two problems here:

## Parsing as JSON

`response.json()` parses the response as JSON and returns a promise that resolves as a JavaScript data structure.

Using `JSON.parse(data)` afterwards doesn't make any sense (except in situations where the HTTP response has been **double** encoded as JSON, in which case you should fix the web service does it doesn't do that).

## Returning undefined

The `console.log` method logs the value you pass to it and returns `undefined`.

So:

> ```
> .then(data => console.log(data))
> ```

passes `undefined` on to the next `then`.

You need to pass the `data`:

```
  fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5500/src/main/resources/savedData.json')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data);
        return data;
    })
    .then(function(obj) {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 
        obj.pages[0].url;
    });
```

---

Or don't add an extra `then` in the first place:

```
  fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5500/src/main/resources/savedData.json')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(function(obj) {
        console.log(obj);
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 
        obj.pages[0].url;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:5500/src/main/resources/savedData.json')
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
    var obj = data;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = 
    obj.pages[0].url;
```

}
);

You don't need to use JSON.parse as you already have a valid Object.
@Quentin gives a good explanation